# Hyperlink to a column that matches todays date

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have a staff rota (the dates are all in cells in seperate columns). I'm trying to create a HYPERLINK to jump to the column with today's date. I have tried the following but this appears it is for rows as opposed to columns. I'm a excel novice so looking for advice.

```
=HYPERLINK("#2"&MATCH(TODAY(),E2:FC2,0)+1,"Jump to Today")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the formula ribbon, there is a tool called "Evaluate Formula" that can be very useful for tracing these kinds of issues.

[image: Button]

It lets you step through the formula one piece at a time so you can see where the error occurs.

[image: Video]

In this case, we get all the way to the final formula and it *seems* to work but the reference isn't valid. That final formula is:

```
=HYPERLINK("#26","Jump to Today")
```

The reference here is `"#26"`. The problem is that's not a valid reference. The [help page for HYPERLINK()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) gives examples of using the function to reference other cells in the same worksheet. It's clunky. You have to include both the file name and the sheet name. That's half the problem. The other half is that `[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!#26` still isn't a valid reference. I think what you want is to select the value in the range `E2:FC2` that has today's today. I would do that using R1C1 notation just because it's easier in this case. The formula would be:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!R2C"&4+MATCH(TODAY(),E2:FC2,0),"Jump to Today")
```

- `Book1.xlsx` is the name of the file.
- `Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet.
- `R2C` starts the R1C1 reference by giving us row 2 and some column.
- `4+MATCH(~)` gives us the right column number based on where today's date is found.

Comment: A reply was made an a proposed edit. Content as follows:
I came up with this for my own needs - linking within the document itself, without using the absolute address of the shared document, which fails as a link. `=HYPERLINK("#R3C"&4+MATCH(TODAY(),D3:CNN3,0),"Jump to Today")` My sheet has a double header row along with a legend in the top left, requiring the address offset to the cell address of 3 rows and 4 columns (to get to the columns with the dates as headers) (#R3C"&4...). I have dates out to end of 2025 resulting in quite a large MATCH range along Row 3 (D3:CNN3).